# pil.image.getdata() returns different pixel information for jpeg and png file

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, pixel

I am trying to get pixel information of two different image files(a .jpg and a .png) using

```
from PIL import Image

#for jpg
im = Image.open('file1.jpg')
pixel_jpg = list(im.getdata())
#for png
im1 = Image.open('file1.png')
pixel_png = list(im.getdata())
```

and result for pixel_jpg and pixel_png are like

```
pixel_jpg = [(27, 45, 19), (26, 44, 20), (26, 44, 20), (26, 44, 20),...]
pixel_png = [(138, 68, 5, 255), (155, 81, 5, 255), (178, 94, 6, 255),...]
```

**What is that extra pixel information available in PNG image and why is that so?**

Comment: This is covered in the [concepts section](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html) of the documentation. Have you checked the `.mode` attribute of the image yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fourth column for `png` is called *alpha* it is used to indicate transparency. Since `jpg` does not have the attribute *alpha* (because it does not support transparency), `.getdata()` will not include them.

`jpg` uses the color scheme RGB and `png` is called RGBA. That's why they returned different results.

As a side note, The last column 255 mean it's fully opaque (0% invisible). Since like the other attributes RGB, it's out of a total of 255.